# How to load URL using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to call a `URL` when the page fully load. so i came up with this

```
$(window).load(function() {

        url: "https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=90.00&tracking=30&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx"
                });
```

**The url was originally like this:**

```
<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx" width="1" height="1">
```

I don't know how to call the `img` tag in a javascript/jquery. So I try to use `url` inside the `load()` function. I really need help.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** *get the url from Image Tag*

```js
$(window).load(function() {
 var  url= $('img').attr('src')
       console.log(url)
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx" width="1" height="1">
```

***Load the url to Image***

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var url="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx";
 var  url= $('img').attr('src',url)
       console.log($('img').attr('src'))
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img  width="1" height="1">
```